How to Maintain a Persistent Red Background in a Windows Forms Application Using Emgu CV
I'm developing a Windows Forms application using C# and Emgu CV where I need to maintain a persistent red background while dynamically overlaying images captured from a webcam. Despite setting the background to red using Graphics.Clear(), the red does not appear as expected, or gets overridden by subsequent drawing operations.
Here's the simplified version of my paint event where I set the background:

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
base.OnPaint(e);
using (var g = e.Graphics)
{
    g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(187, 30, 16)); // Traffic Red
    g.DrawImage(_currentFrame.Bitmap, new Point(0, 0)); // Drawing the webcam feed
} }


Despite this, the background isn't consistently red as intended. The webcam feed is supposed to appear over the red background, but it seems to cover it entirely or the red doesn't show at all. How can I ensure the background remains visible and the images are correctly layered on top?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

First thing, remove this: using (var g = e.Graphics), this is not a Graphics object you created and it's not yours to dispose of. Can't you just set the BackColor of whatever Control you're using to draw the images? It's assumed this is a double-buffered Control

Thanks @Jimi for your help. I have tried red background of the picture box but that coveres only a small area. below is the code for your kind review plz
private void SetupPictureBox()
{
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Ensure PictureBox fills the form
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(187, 30, 16); // Set Traffic Red background
}

What does this mean: background of the picture box but that covers only a small area?  Setting the BackColor of a Control, the entire surface is filled when it's invalidated. Are you omitting some details? -- Have you removed that using statement and the Graphics.Clear() call? -- Since you're overriding OnPaint(), does that mean you have a Custom Control derived from PictureBox, or are you instead painting the background of the Parent Form of this Control? -- If it's a standard Control and you Dock it to fill the entire ClientArea of its parent Form, setting the BackColor is enough

Give some context to the code you have posted, e.g., specifying what Control that override is related to, what is the layout of your Form, i.e., there are other child Controls there etc.

If the layout you're after is a Form with a colored background, a PictureBox that presents the images and a sort of border around the PictureBox, determined by the background Color of the Form, you can simply dock the PictureBox, then use its Margin and/or the Form's Padding to create the required spacing

Find SO examples for changing the background color of an image. You need to create a new Bitmap and Graphics object from it to fill (Clear(...)) with the desired color, draw the original image, and e.Graphics.DrawImage(...); the result. However, that depends on the source images.
